# How to set colorbar labeling text in the center of two tick marks?

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure, colorbar

I am working on a project that involves creating a colorbar for an image using Matplotlib in Python. I have managed to generate the colorbar successfully using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

im = ax.imshow([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

cbar = fig.colorbar(im, orientation='horizontal')
ticks = np.arange(1, 5)
cbar.set_ticks(ticks)
cbar.set_ticklabels(['text 1', 'text 2', 'text 3', 'text4'])

plt.show()
```

However, I would like to customize the colorbar so that the labeling text appears in the center of two tick marks instead of below them. Currently, the text is positioned below the tick marks. Is there a way to achieve this in Matplotlib?

[image]

What I am expecting...

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify it more. You want it between two ticks, like |  text1  | ?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
cbar.set_ticklabels([])
for tick, label in zip(cbar.get_ticks(), ['text 1', 'text 2', 'text 3', 'text 4']):
    cbar.ax.text(tick, 0.5, label, ha='center', va='center')
```

Output:
[image]

**EDIT:**

The edit changes and output can be achieved by calculating the midpoint between two loops. Try the following:

```
cbar.set_ticklabels([])
for i in range(len(ticks)-1):
    tick = (ticks[i] + ticks[i+1]) / 2  
    label = 'text {}'.format(i+1)
    cbar.ax.text(tick, -0.5, label, ha='center', va='top')
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I have made the necessary modifications to your code in order to achieve the desired outcome:

```python
for tick, label in zip(cbar.get_ticks() + 0.5, ['text 1', 'text 2', 'text 3']):
    cbar.ax.text(tick, -0.5, label, ha='center', va='top')
```

These changes have helped me achieve the expected results.

Comment: @Rony Golder I have edited my response and added a method to achieve the output you are expecting.